# Auditing of gdb commands

Tags: linux, audit, gdb

Is there a way I can log all gdb commands executed by a user?
And do user level logging?

Is any other tool like gdbserver can help in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

What the user can do using gdb they can also do directly, so if they want to hide some nefarious activity, it is quite easy to do so (and probably simpler directly than by screwing around with gdb).

What exactly do you want to gain by doing this? Maybe we can suggest a solution to your real problem.

Comment: I want developer to debug process using gdb. But they should not be able to modify variables while debugging. 
Like might be by mistake or intentionally a user modify variable. Which can screw up data on server. 
I want to avoid such failure.

Comment: @VivekGoel The mere act of attaching to a program with a debugger can modify its behavior. You're on the wrong track. If you can't trust these users who'll be running gdb, don't give them access to the machine.